# Linux kernel error when trying to install dconf-editor

Tags: package-management, kernel, dpkg

When running the command

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

I get the output with an error at the end (something about the kernel?) and dconf-editor never installs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dconf-editor
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 390 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,465 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 dconf-editor amd64 3.28.0-1 [390 kB]
Fetched 390 kB in 0s (1,104 kB/s)    
(Reading database ... 187516 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: bluetooth.disable_ertm=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

edit: I see `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: bluetooth.disable_ertm=1: not found` and remember adding the line to `/etc/sysfs.conf` when trying to get my Xbox controller connected, but as I'm still learning about Linux, am not sure what this does (all tutorials only say to add the line, without explaining it), or how/if that is affecting `dpkg`.

Comment: Is there a "rogue" line in `/etc/default/grub`? Open this in gedit (use `gedit admin:/etc/default/grub`) and see if you had accidentally added `bluetooth.disable_ertm=1` into this file. If so, remove it.

Comment: I get the error ```Could not open the file “admin:/etc/default/grub”.``` and ```Unable to handle “admin:” locations.```  Worked fine when I removed the admin: bit though.

Comment: Now when I install dconf-editor though, it installs, but I get ```W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (11 vs 15).
   Affected packages: linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic:amd64```

Comment: 'W:' is a warning, not a fatal error. There are several possible causes. Worry about it only if it keep happening for a couple days.